# remove "," from string if present at end

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to remove `,` from following strings.

1. one,two,three,
2. three,four,five
3. six,seven,eight,nine,ten,

   > ```
   > int strLength = someString.Length;
   >
   > if (strLength > 0)
   > {
   >      findString = findString .Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
   > }
   >
   > if (findString ==",")
   > {
   >      someString.Remove(someString.Length - 1)
   > }
   > ```

I have quickly compiled this code directly in StackExchange editor as an example (It may be have syntax error.

Please take above as logic purpose only.

I would appreciate if someone can provide optimized code for above logic.

**UPDATE**: I actually want to remove  `,` from string if present at the end of string not in middle.

Comment: asking a bunch of programmers for the "best way" almost guarantees 1 response per person :). *best* is too subjective in many cases. Ask for 'the fastest way' or 'least memory usage', etc for more constructive answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A one line option:

```
someString = someString.EndsWith(",") ? someString.Substring(0, someString.Length - 1) : someString;
```

EDIT:

As per [Dilshod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2182401/dilshod)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879210/remove-from-string-if-present/15879377#15879377), this can be expressed as

```
someString = someString.TrimEnd(',');
```

which, IMHO, is better.

Comment: Thanks You got it right... I appreciate other answers but seems to be the short & clean one...

Comment: Well the `yourString = yourString.TrimEnd(',');` answer is shorter and cleaner IMHO...

Comment: Why inventing the wheel again?

Comment: Not sure why, but I falsely assumed TrimEnd would fail if the comma wasn't present. Not that I'm adverse to some SO rep, but yes, TrimEnd is the shortest one liner.

Answer (score 17):

How about this.

```
yourString = yourString.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: This is the best methinks. It's exactly what `TrimEnd()` is for. The only thing to confirm is if the OP wants multiple consecutive commas at the end to all be trimmed rather than just the very last one (pretty sure the answer would be "yes").

Comment: Pay attention that `TrimEnd` removes **all** the trailing occurrences from the string, so if the string has 2 comma in the end `TrimEnd` will remove both.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO. Short and sweet is usually best in terms of readability and long term code support.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Replace function

```
 yourString.Replace(',','');
```

Comment: will this only remove the last `,` from string or all `,`

Comment: for that you should do **yourString= yourString.Remove(yourString.Length - 1);**

Comment: that will remove everything till last starting from the (length of string)-1, in this case, starting from last word only

Comment: There is no such symbol `''`

Comment: well thats an empty string I suppose

Comment: @Deepanshu your code will not complile because there is no empty char symbol in C#

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
if(someString.Last() == ',')
{
    someString = someString.Substring(0, someString.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: I actually want to remove , from string if present at the end of string not in middle.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses can you provide a prooflink for that?

Comment: @Dmitry It doesnt enter the if statement if we take string 1 & 3 as shown in my question.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker You have one string with multiple lines or you have different strings for different lines?

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly look here, string seems to be faster https://compilr.com/eaterofcorpses/charvsstring/main.cs

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses actually on my local machine i have opposite results.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly same on my desktop. My guess is that in mono, replacing with string is most fast and on Windows char is most fast

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're exactly trying to do... replacing "," with "" may be all you need ?
What are the output value you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code below:

```
 string s = "one,two,three,";   
 s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf(","));
```

Comment: Doesn't this remove the last comma that is in the string... Even if it is not the last character in the string

Answer (score 0):

```
someString = someString.Remove(someString.Length - 1);
```

This will remove the last character of the string. Be sure to check the length of the string before you perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 string s = "x,y,";
 if (s.Length > 0 && s.EndsWith(","))
   s = s.TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LastIndexOf()

```
string str="One,Two,Three,";
string newString=str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(',')) //Result= "One,Two,Three";
```

Comment: `str = "One,Two,Three"` result = "One,TwoThree"

Comment: @Sayse: Requirement is to remove ',' from string if present at the end of string not in middle. Please read the UPDATE section in the query.

Comment: I was just letting you know that your code wouldnt work, my initial comment was even wrong, it would return `one,two` I believe